# Prevent input-group-append from pushing neighboring input-group on right

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

so I have this `input-group` with an `input-group-append` button that renders on some condition. However, when I have two `input` fields next to each other and render the `input-group-append` for the first one, this `button` pushes the neighboring right `input` field on right, decreasing its width. This is the sandbox that I use for this example: [code sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-grass-ooeco?file=/src/App.js). As you can see, when I type something in `Recipient's username`, it renders the button and pushes `Recipient's password` on right. I'd like to prevent this and render the button without having any modifications on the `input` fields themselves. [Example without the code.](https://ooeco.csb.app/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Bootstrap's grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) and wrap your 2 inputs in a `col` within a `row`. You don't need to change the input fields, themselves, but would need to add an extra CSS class to both `input-group` divs and add a wrapper div with the class `row`. The HTML would become:

```
<div className="App">
  <div className="row">
    <div className="input-group col-6">
      <input ... />
      {showAppend === true && (
        <div className="input-group-append">
          <span className="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">
            @example.com
          </span>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
    
    <div className="input-group col-6">
      <input... />
      {showAppendPassword === true && (
        <div className="input-group-append">
          <span className="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">
            @example.com
          </span>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This uses the grid system to render both the username and password inputs side by side. I've fixed the width of both divs with the class `input-group` by adding `col-6` (meaning they both take up 50% of the total width). This means, when the `input-group-append` is rendered it will reduce the size of the input it is attached to rather than interfering with the other input:

Without the `input-group-append`:
[image]

With the `input-group-append`:
[image]